# textarea onresize not working

Tags: html, textarea, onresize

according to w3 schools `<textarea>` supports `onresize` however it is not working.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

browsers tried:

Chrome 25.0.1364.172

Safari 6.0.3 (7536.28.10)

Firefox 19.0

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/5abR3/

**update**

as i learned my lesson not to trust w3schools 100%, i found this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize

Comment: don't trust w3 schools: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: anything i can trust?

Comment: @btevfik https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textareas don't resize in MOST(ALL) the browsers  **onresize** event is **NOT WORKING FOR** the window object in this case, you case use jQuery UI plugin:

```
$("idoftextarea").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        $("id").append("yourcode");
    }
});
```

Reference: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: hey thanks. is there a way to add this easily to all textarea elements in the page. i tried `var arr = document.getElementsByTagName ('textarea');` and then iterating `arr` but didn't work.

Comment: `var text = document.getElementsByTagName ('textarea');
for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
text[i].resizable({
    resize: function() {
      alert("AAA");
    }
});
}`

Comment: yse,$("body").find("textarea").reresizable(.... actual i didnt tested but i has to woek

Answer (score 4):

Most browsers only trigger an onresize on the body element.

The best solution I've found so far is the use of the overflow and underflow event listeners in a beautiful hack.

http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/

It's pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

A little workaround :

```
$('textarea').bind('mouseup', function() {
    console.log('resized');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to ravula's answer (my reputation is too low for comments):

JQuery adds a bunch of divs to the resizable element. In my case this destroyed the whole layout. You can get rid of the additional margins / padding by using:

```css
.ui-wrapper {
 padding:0px !important;
 margin:0px !important;
 
}
```

This is certainly not very clean and my cause problems but it worked in my case. I'll update this post if i experience any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I like to stick to vanilla js for whatever reason. so here's a simple solution in vanilla:

```html
<textarea
  onmousedown="storeDimensions(this)"
  onmouseup="onresizeMaybe(this)"
></textarea>

<script>
  function storeDimensions(element){
    element.textWidth = element.offsetWidth;
    element.textHeight = element.offsetHeight;
    element.value = "is it gonna change? we don't know yet...";
  }
  
  function onresizeMaybe(element){
    if (element.textWidth===element.offsetWidth
     && element.textHeight===element.offsetHeight) 
      element.value = "no change.\n";
    else element.value ="RESIZED!\n";
    
    element.value +=
       `width: ${element.textWidth}\n`
      +`height: ${element.textHeight}`;
  }
</script>
```

and for homework, use `onmousemove` to trigger the resize event instead of `onmouseup` (I didn't need that in my particular case).

:) hope it helps someone someday... seeing as how this question is now 5 years old.