# Textarea size inside of CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to use an implicit CSS grid to generate a layout for the following basic HTML structure:

```
<div class='row'>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

where the `.row` div is a CSS grid with an auto-flow set to column for automatically placing elements as columns:

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

I would expect, as with most elements, that the CSS grid would provide equal space to both the `textarea` and the `div` elements along the row. But instead, the layout looks like this:
[image: layout]
The `textarea` takes up more space along the row than expected. When you try to resize the `textarea`, I see the following:
[image: resize]
What seems to be happening here is the grid is adding additional space to the right of the `textarea` equal to the width of the `div` on the right. What I can't figure out is why this is happening, and why the elements don't initially have an equal width. What am I missing here?

I've created a simple JSFiddle for testing this behavior [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pLaefsg3/).

Comment: intresting, It's a complex case of calculation. The texteara resize will have a width set explicitely which will make the behavior different from the initial one before resizeing.

Comment: also note that a textarea has a default width that we can manage with `cols`. If you set `cols=1` it should fix the issue  https://jsfiddle.net/yvsnb4dq/

Answer (score 1):

To make them the same size you need to [ask the grid to do that](https://jsfiddle.net/cwyuh51x/)

```
grid-auto-columns:1fr;
```

You can stop the user resizing the textarea with [`resize:none`](https://jsfiddle.net/dvztpjro/)

---

If you want to get this to work whilst letting the user resize, I couldn't find a [css solution](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

I had an idea but I couldn't get it to work.
The gist was

- have a set of [invisible] divs as a first row
- have a function that can be called on an element of a grid to see if its `offsetWidth` is lesser to one of the hidden divs of the same column
- if it is, [manipulate the css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information) from `auto` to setting the width explicitly to the textarea's for that column, then with some mix of `repeat(x, 1fr)` (pre-textarea columns) &  `repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)` (post-textarea columns)
- then attach this function to the resize ([or mouseup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35664925/2518317)) of the textarea

Alternatively, consider [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
It will have the opposite problem; it wont force an element to be `1fr` (and apply that unwanted padding), but I dont think you can ask it to be `1/<number in row>` in size [in css only] either.

Comment: Yes thank you, that is a simple fix. I'm still left wondering though why the elements are not equally sized to begin with? If you replace the `textarea` with a `div` element, the two divs are equally sized without explicitly setting `grid-auto-columns`.

Comment: Well you're thinking about it the wrong way. It's not that `textarea` is doing something odd, it's that `div` by nature tries to fill the width. `textarea`s are such an element with implicit width (when you dont set it yourself). [Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/cwyuh51x/1/), now that a div has the width, it's borked again

Answer (score 1):

> why the elements don't initially have an equal width. What am I missing here?

`textarea` has a width initially defined by `cols` which has a default value equal to `20`

> **cols**
>
> The visible width of the text control, in average character widths. If it is specified, it must be a positive integer. If it is not specified, the default value is 20.

This width play a role in defining the initial width of the textarea. You can set a small value to make sure it behave *almost* the same as div.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.row > div {
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
    <textarea cols=1></textarea>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

You can still notice a small difference since the textarea is not having an initial width exactly equal to 0 and it also has some padding so its column will logically be a little bigger.

---

To avoid this and to also fix the resize issue better explicitely define the grid like below where you set the initial width of the textarea to be half the width of grid.

I don't know your real use case but I will consider the fact that your grid is full page width (I will also consider the default `body` margin)

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
}

.row > div {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

textarea {
  width:calc(50vw - 16px);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
    <textarea ></textarea>
    <div></div>
</div>
```